# JQuery Mobile - Screen height differs from actual browser height on desktop/samsung galaxy tab

Tags: jquery

I need my content part of the page to occupy whats left from header and footer. While the header and footer are working perfectly, my content is taking something like 42 px of the screen. When printing the height of $(window).height() it gave me 221 px. When printing the height of $(document).height() it gave me 300 px. Is that even possible???

I've tried it on Google Chrome, IE 10 both under Windows 8.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sometitle</title>

    <!-- Setting viewport to match the device width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- JQuery libs imported -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var wnw = parseFloat($(window).width());
            var wnh = parseFloat($(window).height());
            alert(wnw + " " + wnh);

            var scw = parseFloat($(document).width());
            var sch = parseFloat($(document).height());


            alert(scw + " " + sch);
        });
    </script>
</head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="firstpage" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="background: url('./images/someimg.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%;">

        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've seen many post regarding related issues were a number of classes is assigned a height or min-height of 100%, but none seems to work for me.

Thx.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here, but just so we're clear. `$(window)` is the browser viewport,  `$(document)` is the actual size of the document after Markup has been introduced. They will (likely) never be the same unless it was designed that way.